# Doctrine Query Base with grouping and latest record

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a table "table_b" that contain the following details[image: Table Sample]

I would like to use doctrine to query an output with a specific condition. Currently I'm using the block below to query.

```
$table_a= $em->getRepository('table_a')->findOneBy(['id'=>1]);
foreach($table_a->table_b as $records){
    echo $records->name. " : " . $records->value;
}
```

It will output the entire ArrayCollection. Is there a way to query the record base on latest 'Date Created', that is base on the grouping of column 'Foreign Key Table 2'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use native Doctrine query methods, you should use `findOneBy` with the `order by`parameter.

```
findOneBy(['id' => 1], ['DateCreated' => 'desc'])
```

Then, you says the result is an ArrayCollection, so using the `ArrayCollection::first()` method, you'll get the last created element

EDIT

Imagine you have a `Group` entity and a `Member` entity. groups table is your `table_a` and members table is your `table_b`.

Entity description should be something like that :

```
class Group
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="member", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"dateCreated"="DESC"})
     */
    protected $members;

    ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $members = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // members handling accessors

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }

    /**
     * @param $members
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setMembers($members)
    {
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();

        return $this->addMembers($members);
    }

    /**
     * @param $members
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addMembers($members)
    {
        foreach ($members as $member)
        {
            $this->addMember($member);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Member $member
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addMember(Member $member)
    {
        $this->members->add($member);
        $member->setGroup($this);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param Member $member
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeMember(Member $member)
    {
        if ($this->members->contains($member))
        {
            $this->members->removeElement($member);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $members
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function removeMembers($members)
    {
        foreach ($members as $member)
        {
            $this->removeMember($member);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And Member entity :

```
class Member
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="members")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $group;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="date_created")
     */
    protected $dateCreated;

    /**
     * @return Group
     */
    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->group;
    }

    /**
     * @param Group $group
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setGroup(Group $group)
    {
        $this->group = $group;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Now, we have one group with a `dateCreated` ordered collection of members.

Example 1 : You want to get the last member created for a given group

```
$group = $em->getRepository(Group::class)->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
$lastMember = $group->getMembers()->first();
```

Example 2 : You want to get all members created on 2014-01-30 :

```
$members = $group->getMembers()->filter(function (Member $member) {
    return ($member->getDateCreated->format('Y-m-d') == '2014-01-30');
});
```

That's all folk !

PS : I haven't test this code

Comment: Good day, 
I cant do that because the table above is Table_B and its has a Many to One relationship with another table (table_A). I need to find the table_A 1st then only i can look for item in Table_B.

Comment: Please, can you provide your entities description ?

Comment: Check my edit to have an example with ArrayCollection

Answer (score 0):

In TableRepository:

```
public function getLatestRecord()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT t FROM MyBundle:MyEntity t GROUP BY t.table2NameField ORDER BY t.created DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```